# Whats the point of defining a JS variable like so: var appName = appName || {};

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me the reasoning behind using a ternary operator to check if the object exists already before defining it?

```
var message = message || "hello",
    messageOverwritten = "Variable wasn't overwritten",
    messageOverwritten = messageOverwritten || "Variable wasn overwritten";

console.log( message );
console.log( messageOverwritten );​

/* 
 * Output
 *
 * -> hello
 * -> Variable wasn't overwritten
 */
```

Comment: It takes advantage of logical short circuiting and javascript's truthyness to initialize values if they are not set previously.

Comment: That's not the ternary operator. It is in fact binary: `a || b` (where  is c?)

Answer (score 3):

All that's happening here is an "or" statement.  If `message` is `null` or `undefined` for example, it will evaluate to `false` when tested, and the or statement will evaluate to right hand side. Then, the right hand side will be the value set to `message`.

The reasoning behind doing things like this is because some consider it to be less verbose than the alternates:

```
if (!message)
    message = "hello";
```

Comment: A falsy value is a value that is `0`, `false`, `undefined`, `null`, `NaN` or `""` (empty). All of the aforementioned evaluate to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

wsanville is right about what that syntax does and why people use it, but I think you might be asking more what it's useful for. I've seen it mostly used for setting default values for optional variables. Take for instance the function

```
function foo(value){
   value = value || 'hello';
   console.log(value);
}
```

then you can say`foo()` and you'll get 'hello', or `foo('goodbye')` and get 'goodbye'.